# How to compute intersection multiplicity of $l,f$ in the improper point or point of $l$ in the infinity $m_\infty$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I am reading a bit on plane algebraic curves, given the following definitions:

---

If $f$ is a curve and $l$ is a line with equation $Y=aX+b$, the points of $l\cap f$ an be obtained eliminating $Y$ and solving the equation:

$$f_l(X):=f(X,aX+b)=0$$

We have three possibilities:

- $f_l(X)$ is zero, and $l$ is a component of $f$.
- $f_l(X)$ is a constant $\neq 0$, when $f\cap l = \emptyset$
- $f_l(X)$ is a non-constant polynomial that can be written as $f_l(X)=c\prod_{i=1}^{r}(X-x_i)^{m_i}$ where $c$ is a constant and $x_i$ are pairwise distinct roots of the intersection.

**Definition:** The multiplicity or index of intersection of $l,f$ at the point $P$ is given by:

$$
\begin{equation*}
(l,f)_P= \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            0 & \quad P\notin l\cap f \\
            \infty & \quad P\in l \subset f\\
            m_i &\quad P=(x_i,ax_i+b) \text{ as in case 3 above.}
        \end{array}
    \right.
\end{equation*}
$$

---

If $l \not\subset f$, there is an integer:

$$m_\infty = dº f -\sum_{i=1}^{r} m_i$$

Of intersection multiplicity of $l,f$ in the improper point or point of $l$ in the infinity.

---

**QUESTION:** It's not clear to me how to compute this integer. What values of $m_i$ must be summed? I think that given a curve and a line, there is a unique $m_i$ and then, it's not clear to me what are the other values of $m_i$ we must sum in there.

Comment: you should include a reference to where you have found this.

Comment: @hm2020 It's from a Portuguese book. So I don't think it's particularly relevant because people don't read Portuguese.

Comment: If you rewrite the formula you get $dº f =\sum_{i=1}^{r} m_i+m_{\infty}$. It seems you are working with affine coordinates - you should include more information. The number $m_{\infty}$ - is this the intersection multiplicity of the compactification $V(f)$ with the line in projective $2$-space? Bezout theorem says that for any $L,C:=V(F) \subseteq \mathbb{P}^2_k$ with $L$ a line and $C$ a curve, it follows $L \cap C:=deg(F)$ (counted with multiplicity). If $m_1,..,m_r$ are the multiplicities of the intersection points $P_1,..,P_r$ you get the equality...

Comment: ...$deg(f)=deg(F)= m_1+\cdots +m_r$ since $f$ and $F$ have the same degree. Here $V(F)$ is the compactification of $V(f)$ inside the projective plane.

Comment: ...hence intuitively $m_{\infty}$ should be the intersection multiplicity of $V(f)$ with "the point $P_{\infty}$ at infinity". You compactify $V(f)$ to $V(F)$ and calculate $L  \cap V(F)$.

Comment: In Hartshorne Ex.I.5.4 they define and study the intersection multiplicity $m:=(C_1\bullet C_2)_P$ for any two plane affine curves $C_1,C_2$. The number $m$ is defined interms of the local ring $\mathcal{O}_P$ of the point $P$. You should compare your definition to this exercise. Does your book calculate any examples? Include one of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each $m_i$ corresponds to a unique point of intersection $P$ in the affine plane, and you take the sum over all points of intersection. For instance, if you take the curve given by $x^3+y^3=2$ and the line $x+y=1$, you have two intersection points in the affine plane at $(\frac{3-\sqrt{21}}6,\frac{3+\sqrt{21}}6)$ and $(\frac{3+\sqrt{21}}6,\frac{3-\sqrt{21}}6)$, both of which have intersection multiplicity one: $x^3+(1-x)^3=2$ simplifies to $3x^2-3x-1=0$, or $3(x-\frac{3+\sqrt{21}}6)(x-\frac{3-\sqrt{21}}6)=0$. So the sum is $2$, giving that $m_\infty=1$, and sure enough you can check that the two curves intersect with multiplicity one in one point at infinity.

Put another way, for a fixed line $l$, the number $m_\infty$ is the difference in degree between $f(x,y)$ and $f(x,ax+b)$.

---

Separately, have you considered perhaps looking at another source for this intersection multiplicity material? It seems the definition in the text you're looking at [has been somewhat confusing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4308111/questions-regarding-concept-of-multiplicity) and it might help you to see how other texts treat it.

Comment: I thought about looking at other books but I am having classes about this and due to the pandemic, we're having three (remote) semesters in a year. Everything is very fast and in my experience, looking other books leave me more confused. I am finding that it's better to keep in the same book and struggle to clear up any confusion that might occur.